# Quick question about using the QTabWidget 'addTab' function

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

Hopefully a very quick question. In one of my functions I want to generate an 'x' number of tabs for a QTabWidget during run-time ('x' provided by user). I know I have to use the addTab function for the QTabWidget (correct me if I'm wrong), but I am unsure as to how I am supposed to use it. The qt documentation was unclear to me.

I have tried the following command to add only 1 tab as a test, but it caused the program to crash:

```
ui->checkBoxTabArea->addTab(ui->checkBoxTabArea,"tab2");
```

Since I am obviously wrong, can somebody help me use this function? I feel like I am just passing the wrong arguments to addTab.

Edit: checkBoxTabArea already has 1 tab when the program starts up (if this is any help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation, the addTab function says this :

> int QTabWidget::addTab ( QWidget * page, const QString & label )
>
> Adds a tab with the given page and label to the tab widget, and
> returns the index of the tab in the tab bar.

So the argument you pass should not be the TabWidget you want to *add* the tab to, rather it should be the widget you *want to add* as the tab.

What you should do is something like :

```
QLabel *myLabel = new QLabel("Hello World", this);
ui->checkBoxTabArea->addTab(myLabel, "My Label Tab");
```

This will add a single tab to the tab widget, which contains myLabel.